# Unable to connect to SQL Server database from code

Tags: c#

I have tried with following code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = @"Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=Database2;User id=***;Password=***;";

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT * from tableP";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(table);

    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
}
```

Additional information:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: You don't even ask a question, you just throw code at us and expect us to fix it.

Comment: Dear please don't expose your credentials to the outside world.I have edited it.

Comment: Hi, you can try with other connection String with sqlServer in https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the connection the first before performing any operation on database.

```
sqlConn.Open();
```

and try with this connection string

```
connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Database2; User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

Comment: Im still getting the ssame error.

Comment: @user3342777: which error are you getting?

Comment: Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: It would have been nice if you put that information in the question it self.

Comment: i think the `ConnectionString` which OP is using is perfectly Valid.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connString = 'yourconnectionstring'
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    try
    {

        sqlConn.Open();
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT * from tableP";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table);
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        dgv.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        SqlConn.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        SqlConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its still not working.